# Python "statsmodels" not Importing When Using Rodeo IDE

Tags: python, anaconda, statsmodels, rodeo

I installed Anaconda then Rodeo (using the setup file on their website). However, when I run a script I get the error below. The line with problems is:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
```

Strangely this code does run perfectly using the Spyder2 IDE.

Any suggestions?

Steve

```
>>> import statsmodels.api as sm
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-6030a6549dc0> in <module>()
----> 1 import statsmodels.api as sm

C:\Users\steve\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\__init__.py in <module>()
      6 
      7 from warnings import simplefilter
----> 8 from .tools.sm_exceptions import (ConvergenceWarning, CacheWriteWarning,
      9                                   IterationLimitWarning, InvalidTestWarning)
     10 

C:\Users\steve\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tools\__init__.py in <module>()
----> 1 from .tools import add_constant, categorical

C:\Users\steve\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tools\tools.py in <module>()
      7 import numpy.linalg as L
      8 from scipy.linalg import svdvals
----> 9 from statsmodels.distributions import (ECDF, monotone_fn_inverter,
     10                                        StepFunction)
     11 from statsmodels.datasets import webuse

C:\Users\steve\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\distributions\__init__.py in <module>()
----> 1 from .empirical_distribution import ECDF, monotone_fn_inverter, StepFunction
      2 from .edgeworth import ExpandedNormal
      3 

C:\Users\steve\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\distributions\empirical_distribution.py in <module>()
      3 """
      4 import numpy as np
----> 5 from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
      6 
      7 def _conf_set(F, alpha=.05):

C:\Users\steve\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\__init__.py in <module>()
    143 from __future__ import division, print_function, absolute_import
    144 
--> 145 from .interpolate import *
    146 from .fitpack import *
    147 

C:\Users\steve\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\interpolate.py in <module>()
     29 from . import _ppoly
     30 from .fitpack2 import RectBivariateSpline
---> 31 from .interpnd import _ndim_coords_from_arrays
     32 
     33 

scipy\interpolate\interpnd.pyx in init scipy.interpolate.interpnd (scipy\interpolate\interpnd.c:24330)()

C:\Users\steve\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scipy\spatial\__init__.py in <module>()
     89 
     90 from .kdtree import *
---> 91 from .ckdtree import *
     92 from .qhull import *
     93 from ._plotutils import *

ckdtree.pyx in init ckdtree (scipy\spatial\ckdtree\ckdtree.cxx:22661)()

C:\Users\steve\Anaconda2\lib\multiprocessing\__init__.pyc in cpu_count()
    134         return num
    135     else:
--> 136         raise NotImplementedError('cannot determine number of cpus')
    137 
    138 def freeze_support():

NotImplementedError: cannot determine number of cpus
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a dependency on the multiprocessing library in scipy that looks for the number of cores you have available.  We've added detection for this in the latest version but in the meantime you can set the environment variable manually:

```
import os
os.environ["NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS"] = "2"
```